# jQuery replace function is not replacing text in valid HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace some texts in html string but it throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` error.

```
var formHtml = ($('#cx-record-answer-form-div .'+$('#cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit').find('#answer_type').val()).html());
```

In the console when I logged the `formHtml` variable it says that `formData` is *undefined* but when I remove `.html()` from the end of the above code it returns valid html. But still the replace function is throwing the undefined error!

**JS:**

```
var $addAnswerButton = $('#add-answer-button');
var newAnswerFormIndex =  0;

$addAnswerButton.on('click', function() {
    newAnswerFormIndex++;

    if($.trim($('#cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit').find('#answer_type').val()) != ''){
        // get form html
        var formHtml = ($('#cx-record-answer-form-div .'+$('#cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit').find('#answer_type').val()).html());
        console.log(formHtml);
        var appendFormHtml = formHtml.replace('cx-record-answer-form-<#id#>','cx-record-answer-form-new-'+newAnswerFormIndex);
        console.log(appendFormHtml);

        appendFormHtml = appendFormHtml.replace(/\<#id#>/g,newAnswerFormIndex);
        appendFormHtml = appendFormHtml.replace('bootstrapSwitch-class','bootstrapSwitch');
        $('#answer-container').append(appendFormHtml);

    }
});
```

**HTML Markup:**

```
<form id="cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit">
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="label">Select type</label>
                <label class="input">
                    <select id="answer_type" name="answer_type" class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" data-bind="select2Binding: answer_type, select2Options: { data: listAnswerTypes, width: &quot;100%&quot;, placeholder: &quot;Select a type...&quot;}" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                        <option value="0">Free Text</option><option value="1">Multiple</option></select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--open" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-answer_type-container" aria-owns="select2-answer_type-results"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-answer_type-container" title="Multiple">Multiple</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>                                            </label>
                </section>
        </div>
        <button id="add-answer-button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" type="button">Add Answer</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success cx-btn-submit" type="submit">Save Question</button>
</form>

<div id="answer-container"></div>

<div id="cx-record-answer-form-div" class="hide">
    <div class="multiple">
        <form id="cx-record-answer-form-<#id#>" data-answer-id="<#id#>" class="cx-record-answer-form smart-form" data-edit-allowed="true">
            <section class="col col-4">
                <label class="label">Answer</label>
                <label class="input">
                    <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer" data-bind="value: answer">                </label>
            </section>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If `$` is really jQuery then `$('#cx-record-answer-form-div .'+$('#cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit').find('#answer_type').val())` won't ever return "html"

Comment: This is invalid - `($('#cx-record-answer-form-div .'+$('#cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit')`. Your `formHtml` is undefined.

Comment: @randomSoul This is only "invalid" when you ignore the parts you've removed. And even without the removed parts it will only generate an invalid selector. But also in this case `formHtml` won't be `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`($('#cx-record-answer-form-div .'+$('#cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit')` is incorrect. If you want to get the value of select with id `answer_type` use - `$('#cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit').find('#answer_type').val()`.

```js
var $addAnswerButton = $('#add-answer-button');
var newAnswerFormIndex = 0;

$addAnswerButton.on('click', function() {
  newAnswerFormIndex++;

  if ($.trim($('#cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit').find('#answer_type').val()) != '') {
    // get form html
    var formHtml = ($('#cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit').find('#answer_type').val());
    console.log(formHtml);
    var appendFormHtml = formHtml.replace('cx-record-answer-form-<#id#>', 'cx-record-answer-form-new-' + newAnswerFormIndex);
    console.log(appendFormHtml);

    appendFormHtml = appendFormHtml.replace(/\<#id#>/g, newAnswerFormIndex);
    appendFormHtml = appendFormHtml.replace('bootstrapSwitch-class', 'bootstrapSwitch');
    $('#answer-container').append(appendFormHtml);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col col-6">
      <label class="label">Select type</label>
      <label class="input">
                    <select id="answer_type" name="answer_type" class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" data-bind="select2Binding: answer_type, select2Options: { data: listAnswerTypes, width: &quot;100%&quot;, placeholder: &quot;Select a type...&quot;}" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                        <option value="0">Free Text</option><option value="1">Multiple</option></select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--open" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-answer_type-container" aria-owns="select2-answer_type-results"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-answer_type-container" title="Multiple">Multiple</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>                                            </label>
    </section>
  </div>
  <button id="add-answer-button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" type="button">Add Answer</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success cx-btn-submit" type="submit">Save Question</button>
</form>

<div id="answer-container"></div>

<div id="cx-record-answer-form-div" class="hide">
  <div class="multiple">
    <form id="cx-record-answer-form-<#id#>" data-answer-id="<#id#>" class="cx-record-answer-form smart-form" data-edit-allowed="true">
      <section class="col col-4">
        <label class="label">Answer</label>
        <label class="input">
                    <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer" data-bind="value: answer">                </label>
      </section>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Edit -

From the line of code `($('#cx-record-answer-form-div .'+$('#cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit').find('#answer_type').val()).html());` it seems like you want to get the `html` of `div` with class `multiple` nested inside `div` with `id` `cx-record-answer-form-div` and you want to get the class name `multiple` dynamically from the first select dropdown.

The line - `find('#answer_type').val()` will return either `0` or `1`. Instead use `text()` to get text content of the selected option.

```js
var $addAnswerButton = $('#add-answer-button');
var newAnswerFormIndex =  0;

$addAnswerButton.on('click', function() {
    newAnswerFormIndex++;

    if($.trim($('#cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit').find('#answer_type').val()) != ''){
        // get form html
        const selectedOption = $('#cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit').find('#answer_type option:selected').text().toLowerCase();
        const formHtml = $('#cx-record-answer-form-div .' + selectedOption).html();
        console.log('Before Replace ', formHtml);
        if(formHtml) {
            let appendFormHtml = formHtml.replace('cx-record-answer-form-<#id#>', 'cx-record-answer-form-new-' + newAnswerFormIndex);
            console.log('After Replace ', appendFormHtml);
            // var appendFormHtml = formHtml.replace('cx-record-answer-form-<#id#>','cx-record-answer-form-new-'+newAnswerFormIndex);
            // console.log(appendFormHtml);
             
            // appendFormHtml = appendFormHtml.replace(/\<#id#>/g,newAnswerFormIndex);
            // appendFormHtml = appendFormHtml.replace('bootstrapSwitch-class','bootstrapSwitch');
            // $('#answer-container').append(appendFormHtml);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="cx-user-survey-questions-record-edit">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col col-6">
      <label class="label">Select type</label>
      <label class="input">
                    <select id="answer_type" name="answer_type" class="select2 select2-hidden-accessible" data-bind="select2Binding: answer_type, select2Options: { data: listAnswerTypes, width: &quot;100%&quot;, placeholder: &quot;Select a type...&quot;}" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                        <option value="0">Free Text</option><option value="1">Multiple</option></select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--open" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-answer_type-container" aria-owns="select2-answer_type-results"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-answer_type-container" title="Multiple">Multiple</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>                                            </label>
    </section>
  </div>
  <button id="add-answer-button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" type="button">Add Answer</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success cx-btn-submit" type="submit">Save Question</button>
</form>

<div id="answer-container"></div>

<div id="cx-record-answer-form-div" class="hide">
  <div class="multiple">
    <form id="cx-record-answer-form-<#id#>" data-answer-id="<#id#>" class="cx-record-answer-form smart-form" data-edit-allowed="true">
      <section class="col col-4">
        <label class="label">Answer</label>
        <label class="input">
                    <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer" data-bind="value: answer">                </label>
      </section>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

The replace will work, only if you select option two with text `multiple` because there does not exist html code with `#cx-record-answer-form-div .free text`. `appendFormHtml.replace(/\<#id#>/g,newAnswerFormIndex);` is not required because it is already replaced in `formHtml.replace`. As well `formHtml` do not have `bootstrapSwitch-class`. So the line `appendFormHtml = appendFormHtml.replace('bootstrapSwitch-class','bootstrapSwitch');` won't replace anything.

Comment: you're right about getting value of select but I want to get `$('#cx-record-answer-form-div` div html also so therefore I have added concatenation !